# For What Valus of $a \in \mathbb{N}$ Does $y=x^a e^x$ Has Only One Extreme Point?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, maxima-minima

The solution is every odd $a$, but I have a little bit of trouble getting it.

Here's what I got:
$$y=x^a e^x\\
y'= ax^{a-1}e^x+x^ae^x \\
y' = e^x(ax^{a-1}+x^a) = 0\\
ax^{a-1}+x^a=0\\
\frac{ax^a}{x}+x^a=0\\
x^a(\frac{a}{x}+1)=0\\
$$
$x=0, -a$ are the suspicious points. It seemes that the "only one extreme point" is $0$, which means that $x=-a$ should not be an extreme point in some cases.

This itself is weird because $y'$ is not defined at $0$...

How do I continue from there? Help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Edit: in "extreme point" I mean local maximum or minimum and not inflection point.

Comment: it really depends what the phrase "extreme point" means.  When $a$ is odd, then there is a critical point at $x=0,$ and this is a horizontal inflection point. If an "extreme point" must be a local maximum or a local minimum, then $0$ would not count. Suggest you draw careful graphs of $x e^x$ and $x^2 e^x$

Comment: Your statement that "$y'$ is not defined at $0$" is wrong.  It is very well defined.  Look closely to see where and why you made this mistake.

Comment: $y'=y'= ax^{a-1}e^x+x^ae^x$ **IS** defined at $0$.  It's $\frac {y'}{xe^x} = x^a(\frac{a}{x}+1)$ that is not defined at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Better if you write
$y'
=e^xx^{a-1}(a+x)
$.

Then $y' = 0$ at
$x = -a$.

For $y'$ to have another root,
it must be at $x = 0$
with $a > 1$.

I don't know where
your answer of
"every odd $a$"
came from,
but consider $a = 2$.

Then
$y = x^2e^x$
so 
$y'
=e^xx(x+2)
$
which is zero at
$x = -2$ and $x = 0$

Comment: Not all zeros of $f'$ give local extrema.

Comment: In this case it does.